# Let X and Y be two independent Bernoulli variables of parameter $\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be two independent Bernoulli variables of parameter $\frac{1}{3}$.

Let U = $X \cdot Y$ and $V = X + Y$.  I want to calculate:
$$ \mathbb{P}( V = 0 | U = 0)$$
That is, the probability that $V = 0$ knowing that $U = 0$. My reasoning is the following: if $U=0$, then for sure X is $0$ or Y is $0$. For V to be zero I also need the other one to be 0, that happens with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, that would be my final answer. However, the solution should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X,Y)$ are independent $\text{Ber}(p)$ variables with $p=1/3=1-q$.

You have \begin{align}\Pr(V=0,U=0)&=\Pr(X+Y=0,XY=0)\\&=\Pr(X=0,Y=0)\\&=\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)\\&=q^2\end{align}

and \begin{align}\Pr(U=0)&=\Pr(XY=0)\\&=\Pr(\{X=0\}\cup \{Y=0\})\\&=\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(Y=0)-\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)\\&=2q-q^2\end{align}

So, $\Pr(V=0\mid U=0)=\Pr(V=0,U=0)/\Pr(U=0)=\frac{q^2}{2q-q^2}=\cdots$